# Extract text in R between keywords

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have text extracted from PDFs that looks something like this:

`String<-"A recorded vote was taken. In favour: Vanuatu, Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of), Viet  Nam, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe Against: None Abstaining: Malawi, Palau The draft resolution"`

I would like to extract the countries that were in favour, against and abstaining.

So what I did so far was

```
library(stringr)
in.fav<-str_locate_all(String, "In favour:")[[1]]
against<-str_locate_all(String, "Against:")[[1]]
abstain<-str_locate_all(String, "Abstaining:")[[1]]
```

to get the location of the keywords, `"In favour:"`, `"Against:"` and `"Abstaining:"`.

I then extracted the countries in favour and against using:

```
Favour<str_trim(str_sub(String,start=in.fav[1,"end"]+1,end=against[1,"start"]-1))
```

`Against<str_trim(str_sub(String,start=against[1,"end"]+1,end=abstain[1,"start"]-1))`

but I am struggling to get the countries that abstained, Malawi and Palau since there is no specific keyword that marks the end of the abstaining countries.

I thought I could predefine a list of country names

```
Names<-c("Vanuatu", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", "Viet  Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe", "Malawi", "Palau")
```

and then look at

`str_sub(String,start=abstain[1,"start"]+1)`

to extract until the first word is not contained in `Names`, but I did not succeed.
Any help or other ideas how to efficiently get the list of countries that were in favour, against and abstained would be very much appreciated.
More specifically, the output I would like to have something like this:

`Results<-list()`

`Results$favour<-c("Vanuatu, Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of), Viet  Nam, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe")`

`Results$against<-c("None")`

`Results$abstain<-c("Malawi", "Palau")`

Many thanks. Martin

Comment: Please include the exact output you expect here.

Comment: Just clarified it. Thanks.

Comment: Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/UsZK9e/1) help somewhat?

Comment: Regex can only deal with regular language. You ask for something regex can't do (extract out of context grammar that contains some semantics regex is unaware of). Please add the rules that can be used to extract what you need, else, it is unclear.

Comment: Regex can do the first two (in favour and against), see the answer from JvdV. I am struggling with the third (abstain) and did not mean that the answer has to involve regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`you could try:

```
String<-"A recorded vote was taken. In favour: Vanuatu, Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of), Viet  Nam, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe Against: None Abstaining: Malawi, Palau The draft resolution"

# get those in favor
in.fav <- str_extract(String, "(?<=In favour: ).*(?=Against)") 
# get those against
against <- str_extract(String, "(?<= Against: ).*(?=Abstaining)")
# get those abstaining
# assuming the end of the sentence is always (The bill <blank>)
abstaining <- str_extract(String, "(?<= Abstaining: ).*(?=The)")
```

You can then turn that into a list:

```
str_split(in.fav, ", ") -> in.fav.list
str_split(against, ", ") -> against.list
str_split(abstaining, ", ") -> abstain.list
```

which will produce (for the in favor countries):

```
[[1]]
[1] "Vanuatu"                            "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)" "Viet  Nam"                          "Yemen"                              "Zambia"                            
[6] "Zimbabwe "
```

EDIT: since The is not always the first word after the countries in the Abstaining catagory:

```
abstaining <- str_extract(String, "(?<=Abstaining: )")
str_split(abstaining, ", ") -> abstain.list

#Create vector of countries
country.list <- c(countries)

#Create new list for updated abstained countries
abstain.list.updated <- list()
k <- 1

for(i in 1:length(abstain.list[[1]])){
 if(abstaining[[1]][i] %in% country.list){
  abstaining[[1]][i] -> abstain.list.updated[[k]]
  k <- k + 1
 }
}
```

The resultant list will be a tad messier than above, but you can tweek the `for()` loop to produce a nicer output.

Comment: Thank you Justin. This solution is much more elegant than mine. However, it is not always that the abstaining countries end where "The" starts. So the expression (?=The), will not work generally, that is my main problem here. Martin

Comment: Ya it gets tricky then. I think your best bet would be to extract all characters after the abstaining indicator, then turn it into a list as above then remove the elements if they are not present in a vector of country names. Although this will be time intensive given how many countries there are. Are all countries who vote the same? Maybe that would narrow down your processing time. I put an edit above of what it might look like.

Comment: Thank you. The list of potential countries is specified in the example above by Names. Your workaround gives me an error, this abstaining <- str_extract(String, "(?<=Abstaining: )") does return "". Would you have another look? Best, Martin

Comment: I'm sorry - could you copy the exact error? I'm assuming its because there is either no abstaining or no words after abstain. Could you also paste the sentence on which you're trying the extract?

Comment: The error is this:  `abstaining <- str_extract(String, "(?<=Abstaining: )")` gives `abstaining`  ` ""`